# SQL join tables if one string appears in another string

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say if have two tables

Table A:

```
**Middle_name**
John
Joe
Fred
```

Table B:

```
**Full_name**
Billy, Joe-Bob
JasonFredAnderson
Tom John Jefferson
```

I want to join the tables on `Middle_name` and `Full_name`.

I've tried using partial string matching like below but that hasn't worked. For some reason it doesn't match full names with a comma before the middle name. Using postgres.

```
SELECT Full_name, Middle_name
FROM B
JOIN A
ON B.Full_name LIKE CONCAT('%', A.Middle_name, '%')
```

To reiterate, the above query would join `Fred` and `John` correctly, but not `Joe`, since `Billy, Joe-Bob` has a comma before `Joe`.

Comment: I don't believe that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm sorry what?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible test case (`CREATE`, `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements)?

Comment: There is also`POSITION(...)` , avoiding the `%` and the concat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this using the POSITIION() function this way:

```
SELECT Full_name, Middle_name
FROM B
JOIN A
ON POSITION(Middle_name IN Full_name)>0
```